# AWS S3 Query String Request Authentication Alternative Upload a file

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Has anyone successfully done this?

My idea is to post to a servlet and it will respond with Query String Request Authentication url after the servlet has authenticated the user. The user will then use this url to upload a picture file.

Was wondering if this is even possible.

The thing I don't get is how do you transfer the picture from your computer or device to the s3.

This is the StringToSign:

```
PUT\n
(content here?)\n
image/jpeg\n
1175139620\n
/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg
```

How do I inser the content into the string to sign? Do i base64 it first then md-5 it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is very much possible. You will only have to deal with how would like to send the URL back after creating the pre signed URL. Maybe as XML or as plain text..

I would recommend using the jets3t  library to create the URL. You could call this API:

org.jets3t.service.S3Service.createSignedPutUrl(String, String, Map, Date, boolean)

You could also an IAM policy instead. But your way is easier.

Edit: Added more information..

That's the beauty of it, when you are using the jets3t library you dont need to any of that. 
Just call the method :

```
 S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(awsCredentials);
// Create a signed HTTP PUT URL valid for 5 minutes.
   String putUrl = s3Service.createSignedPutUrl(bucket.getName(), object.getKey(),
        object.getMetadataMap(), expiryDate, false);
```

And use the URL to upload your image like below:

```
SignedUrlHandler signedUrlHandler = new RestS3Service(null);
S3Object object = new S3Object(bucket,<your file object goes here>);
 S3Object putObject = signedUrlHandler.putObjectWithSignedUrl(putUrl, object);
```

**Edit for signedGetURL():**

Only the ones with ProviderCredential being passed in are deprecated.. This one is not :

http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/api/org/jets3t/service/S3Service.html#createSignedGetUrl(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Date)

You wouldnt need to pass the credentials into this method anyway. Its only the s3service object that needs the credentials.. like this...

```
S3Service s3service=new RestS3Service(credentials); // pass your credentials here
String createSignedGetUrl = s3service.createSignedGetUrl(storageObject.getBucketName(),
    storageObject.getKey(),new DateTime().plusMinutes(5).toDate());
```

Comment: The part I don't get is the StringToSign. Refer to main post added more stuff.

Comment: Updated my answer. I am not exactly sure internally how the jets3t library takes care of this. But that's one of the goodness of java isn't it, download a library and call the API's as per the docs.

Comment: Ok will look into it. I'm trying to understand how it works if I don't use jets3t.

Comment: Hmmm createSignedGetUrl is deprecated any idea what is the equivalent of this?

Comment: Thanks!, It all works now. Just for discussion, is there a library equivalent to be used for the iPhone development?

Comment: Your welcome.. I am sorry I wouldn't know.. I am a java developer.. never used cocoa.. But I am sure there must be.. Another question in SO maybe?

Comment: I realized that the S3Object must be present to retrieve the MetadataMap, so if I apply my idea above, the device needs to upload the meta-data and file name of the image to the servlet to create the pre-signed put url to return to the device to use to upload the image to S3, is this how it would be done?

Comment: Good question.. I havent tried a signed put URL before.. But to me it makes sense to send/upload the metadata map to the servlet, let it construct the put url using the metadata that you have sent. Use that to then upload your S3Object.. Whether the metadata map that you set directly to S3Object would work, I am not sure. My guess is it shouldn't.  Was that your question?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. Will test around otherwise currently I have to stick to the old method of base64 encode and send to servlet b4 uploading.

Comment: There is no such method as setMetaData so your guess is as good as mine. I think it's not possible.

Comment: hi I just want to ask if there's any javascript library that has the same functionality as jets3t library?